# what is the alternative to prefixing .data with rlang

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

```r
m <- 10
mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(disp = rlang::.data$disp * .env$m)
```

The above does not work.

The goal is to be able to remove the `importFrom rlang .data` that my package has.

What is the alternative way to achieve that if the prefix method does not work?

Comment: Why can't you use `disp` i.e. `mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(disp = disp * .env$m)`. Based on the example, the `disp` doesn't need any `.data$`.  Even in grouped data

Comment: As far as I can tell (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), `.data` is a `dplyr` thing ... and it's just a pronoun, so not something exported as `dplyr::.data`. Perhaps `mutate(disp = cur_data()$disp * .env$m)`?

Comment: @akrun yes you correct, for this particular example, it isn't needed

Comment: @r2evans the example worked. But will it work in general? i.e., where ever there is `.data`, I can replace it with `cur_data()`?

Comment: @free_lions_n_tigers_from_cages no, it depends on the context.  `cur_data()` only works in certain cases

Comment: I think so but I'm not sure. Another alternative is to use `mutate(disp = .data$disp * .env$m)` and add `utils::globalVariables(".data")` somewhere in your package (not within a function) so that R check won't complain about `.data` being uninitialized and not found. (I have not verified that R-check complains about it, but ... try it for yourself :-)

Comment: Actually, from that same link, use `#' @importFrom rlang .data`. So I guess it *is* an `rlang` thing, my bad. (I got that from the section conveniently titled *"Eliminating `R CMD check` NOTEs"* :-)

Comment: Try assigning `d <-rlang::.data` and `e <- rlang::.env`. I was able to get the check past that problem, but not the recognizing the `%>%` pipe problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467297/9349302) `dplyr::cur_data_all()` should be an alternative which works instead of `.data`. I have not yet seen a case where `cur_data_all()` doesn't work **inside data-masking dplyr verbs**, but `.data` does. We can also access grouping variables, which doesn't work with `cur_data()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  transmute(x = cur_data()[["cyl"]],
            y = .data[["cyl"]],
            z = cur_data_all()[["cyl"]]) 
#> # A tibble: 32 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>      cyl     y     z
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     6     6     6
#>  2     6     6     6
#>  3     4     4     4
#>  4     6     6     6
#>  5     8     8     8
#>  6     6     6     6
#>  7     8     8     8
#>  8     4     4     4
#>  9     4     4     4
#> 10     6     6     6
#> # … with 22 more rows
```

However, outside of dplyr verbs `cur_data_all()` cannot be used, while `.data` will work depending on the context. This is the case in `tibble`s for example:

```r
library(dplyr)

tibble(new = 1,
       new2 = .data$new)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>     new  new2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1

tibble(new = 1,
       new2 = cur_data_all()$new)
#> Error in context_peek("mask", fun): `cur_data_all()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
```

Although `cur_data()` and `cur_data_all()` throw an error saying they can only be used **inside dplyr verbs** this is only half true. They can only be used inside **data-masking dplyr verbs**. However, this also holds true for `.data` which won't work in verbs supporting tidy selection:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  select(6)
#>                        wt
#> Mazda RX4           2.620
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       2.875
#> Datsun 710          2.320
#> Hornet 4 Drive      3.215
#> Hornet Sportabout   3.440
#> Valiant             3.460
...

mtcars %>% 
  select(first(.data$cly)) # should be 6 the same as above
#> Error in stop_fake_data_subset(): Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask context.

mtcars %>% 
  select(first(cur_data_all()$cly)) # should be 6 the same as above
#> Error in context_peek("mask", fun): `cur_data_all()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This needs to work inside a package.

Comment: My understanding, which might be wrong, is that the package is using dplyr and that the goal is to only get rid of the direct dependency to rlang. In this case replacing `.data` with `cur_data_all()` should work. Of course there would still be an indirect dependency to rlang.