# difference between .data and cur_data()

Tags: r, dplyr

```r
m <- 10
mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(disp = .data$disp * .env$m)
```

is equivalent to

```r
m <- 10
mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(disp = cur_data()$disp * .env$m)
```

Can you give an example where `cur_data()` and `.data` will yield different results?

I am told that `cur_data()` and `.data` are not interchangeable in all contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within group_by `.data` still includes all columns but `cur_data()` excludes the group_by column(s).  For example, below `cur_data()[["cyl"]]`  is NULL because cyl is a group by column so x does not appear in the result whereas y does appear.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(x = cur_data()[["cyl"]], y = .data[["cyl"]]) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  names
##  [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
## [11] "carb" "y"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70453975/use-levene-test-in-map-function-from-purrr/70454606#70454606) which shows different results/error

```
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)
data %>%
     summarise(across(where(is.numeric),
      ~  cur_data() %>%
       levene_test(reformulate("Treatment", response = cur_column())))) %>%
    unclass %>% 
     bind_rows(.id = 'flux')
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  flux    df1   df2 statistic     p
  <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 flux1     1     8     0.410 0.540
2 flux2     1     8     2.85  0.130
3 flux3     1     8     1.11  0.323
data %>%
     summarise(across(where(is.numeric),
      ~  .data %>%
       levene_test(reformulate("Treatment", response = cur_column())))) %>%
     unclass %>% 
     bind_rows(.id = 'flux')
```

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
> ℹ `..1 = across(...)`.
> ✖ cannot coerce class ‘"rlang_data_pronoun"’ to a data.frame
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                    .Label = c("S1 ", "S2 ", "S3 "), class = "factor"), 
                   plot = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
                                    .Label = c(" Tree 1 ", " Tree 2 ", " Tree 3 "), class = "factor"), 
                   Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("T1", "T2"), class = "factor"), 
                   flux1 = c(11.52188065, 8.43156699, 4.495312274, -1.866676811, 3.861102035, -0.814742373, 6.51039536, 4.767950345, 10.36544542, 1.065963875), 
                   flux2 = c(0.142259208, 0.04060245, 0.807631744, 0.060127596, -0.157762562, 0.062464942, 0.043147603, 0.495001652, 0.34363348, 0.134183704), 
                   flux3 = c(0.147506197, 1.131009714, 0.038860728, 0.0176834, 0.053191593, 0.047591306, 0.00573377, -0.034926075, 0.123379247, 0.018882469))
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing answers:

In the [vignette linked in the comments](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) we find the following quote:

> Note that .data is not a data frame; it’s a special construct, a
> pronoun, that allows you to access the current variables either
> directly, with .data$x or indirectly with .data[[var]]. **Don’t expect
> other functions to work with it.**

It is important to understand that `.data` is a special construct which is just there to help us access variables. It is neither a `data.frame` nor a `function`. Apart from `[[` and `$` most other functions won't work with `.data`. Even `[` won't work. Let's say we want to access more than one variable with `.data`. If `.data.` would be a `data.frame` the following would work, but it doesn't:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  transmute(new = list(.data[c("disp", "hp")]))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `new`.
#> i `new = list(.data[c("disp", "hp")])`.
#> x `[` is not supported by .data pronoun, use `[[` or $ instead.
```

`cur_data()` on the other hand is a function which returns us the current data without grouping variables as `tibble` (even if the underlying data is just a `data.frame`).

In terms of speed `cur_data()` has a very small overhead, compared to `.data` or to just accessing the variable without prefix. Lets take a middle-sized dataset as example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

bench::mark(iterations = 5000L,
            "none" = mutate(flights, new = arr_time),
            ".data" = mutate(flights, new = .data$arr_time),
            "cur_data()" = mutate(flights, new = cur_data()$arr_time))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 none         1.56ms   1.69ms      578.   132.9MB     15.1
#> 2 .data        1.53ms   1.72ms      551.    24.7KB     14.4
#> 3 cur_data()    1.6ms   1.77ms      535.    33.5KB     14.7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In terms of interchangeability I see the following differences:

1. `.data` can't be used as a `data.frame`, this means it won't return the underyling data, unlike `cur_data()`.
2. `.data` can only be used to access one variable at a time by using `[[` or `$`, whereas `cur_data()` returns a `tibble` and will work with all functions that apply to `tibble`s and `data.frame`s.
3. In terms of speed there is no big overhead using `cur_data()`, at least not for middle-sized data sets. This should be verified with bigger data with more columns.
4. `.data` can be used to access grouping variables, which is not possible with `cur_data()`. However, `cur_data_all()` is a similar function which also returns the current data, but including the grouping variables. This later function should be completely interchangeable with `.data`, at least I cannot come up with a case where it's not possible to use both.

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  transmute(x = cur_data()[["cyl"]],
            y = .data[["cyl"]],
            z = cur_data_all()[["cyl"]]) 

#> # A tibble: 32 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>      cyl     y     z
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     6     6     6
#>  2     6     6     6
#>  3     4     4     4
#>  4     6     6     6
#>  5     8     8     8
#>  6     6     6     6
#>  7     8     8     8
#>  8     4     4     4
#>  9     4     4     4
#> 10     6     6     6
#> # … with 22 more rows
```